# C# Winforms - After selecting an Option from a ComboBox allow the mouse scrolling feature to be used without clicking on another control

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, mousewheel, deselect

In my C# winforms application I'm using a TabControl with a FlowLayoutPanel. I have certain controls that will add different UserControls to the FlowLayoutPanel and potentially enable the AutoScroll feature of the tabControl, if the controls are bigger than the predefined TabControl space.

My Problem:

When a ComboBox value is selected I cannot scroll with the mouse wheel until I click on another control. Currently the mouse scroll selection style of the ComboBox is false. I want the user to be able to click anywhere on the TabControl and re-enable the mouse scroll.

I have tried using the MouseClick event but it is only triggered when one of the tabs is clicked with the mouse.

I do not want to:
     add a panel or any other controls to bypass this feature.
     add a Control.Focus() at the end of every ComboBox

Any Suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I have no desire to use the comboBox.MouseWheel feature, the selection style is fine. I want the user to be able to click anywhere outside of the combobox and have the highlighted selection not be highlighted anymore so the mouse wheel can scroll through the tab page

Comment: tried `DropDownStyle` property?

Comment: Have you tried `this.Parent.Focus();`?